# How to read contacts on Android 2.0

Tags: android, contacts, android-2.0-eclair

I'm working on Android 2.0 and am trying to receive a list of all contacts.

Since *android.provider.Contacts.People* is deprecated, I have to use *android.provider.ContactsContract*, But I can't find a proper example of how to use it (ex: retrieve a list of all contacts on the phonebook).

Anyone knows where to find such an example?

Comment: I'd really like to know this as well. I can only find examples on the old method.

Answer (score 161):

First, ensure that you have added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file, then you can loop through your phone contacts like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null); 
while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
   String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( 
   ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)); 
   String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)); 
   if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) { 
      // You know it has a number so now query it like this
      Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null); 
      while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
         String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                 
      } 
      phones.close(); 
   }

   Cursor emails = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null); 
   while (emails.moveToNext()) { 
      // This would allow you get several email addresses 
      String emailAddress = emails.getString( 
      emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)); 
   } 
   emails.close();
}
cursor.close();
```

Additionally, you can loop through your contacts and simply get the name and phone number like this:

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

while(people.moveToNext()) {
   int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
   String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
   int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
   String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
}

people.close();
```

Furthermore, if you need to get things like notes from a contact then you will need to use a different URI, like the following (feel free to use this method):

```
private String getNote(long contactId) { 
   String note = null; 
   String[] columns = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE }; 
   String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
   String[] whereParameters = new String[]{Long.toString(contactId), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
   Cursor contacts = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, whereParameters, null); 
   if (contacts.moveToFirst()) { 
      rv = contacts.getString(0); 
   } 
   contacts.close(); 
   return note; 
}
```

Notice this time I used not only the contact id but the mime type for the query.

Comment: That was perfect Javier, thanks for this, I had to adapt it a bit for my purpose (check if a contact is in to avoid adding again). Here is my code if you want to add it to your post :    
String[] contactNameColumn = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME };
  Cursor checkContactInDatabase = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactNameColumn,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + "=" + "'" + name + "'", null, null);
if (checkContactInDatabase.moveToFirst()) {
int nameFieldColumnIndex = checkContactInDatabase.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);

Comment: String contact = checkContactInDatabase.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
   Toast.makeText(Contact.this, contact + " " + getString(R.string.alreadySaved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
   i.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
   i.putExtra(Insert.NAME, name);
   i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, phone);
   i.putExtra(Insert.COMPANY, companie);
   i.putExtra(Insert.POSTAL, adresse);
   startActivity(i);
  }

  checkContactInDatabase.close();

Comment: Hi, I am getting false always at this statement                     if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)); even though hasPhone has value = "1"

Comment: Sephy, thanks for your additions. Vamsi, this is pretty old code at this point. Android's access to the contacts provider radically changed after 2.1 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Instead of emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.CommonDataColumns.DATA)); you can also use  emailAddress = emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));

Comment: How would you get the contact photo? Ive seen many so-called solutions on SO, but they are largely unreliable...

Comment: It's funny this answer got so many up votes. If you do a test run you'll see that you can never get phone numbers. All because of a funny grammar error: **Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)**. This **parseBoolean** will only return true if the string is "true". However in this answer's case the string being parsed is always "1" instead of "true".

Comment: I was trying to just get the name and phone number from the contacts. Thus i used the second code but it didn't work so i followed the code here http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/06/get-phone-contacts-details-in-android_6.html and it worked perfectly.

Comment: The second method does not work. No wonder this has not been accepter as the correct answer.

Comment: What if The contact has multiple number, will it allow me to choose one? Or will it pick a random one?

Comment: First example very inefficient! For n records it is n+2 query!

Answer (score 22):

Great to see some useful info, it is frustrating how poorly this important topic is covered by docs and such. After too much hacking about I thought I would share a little code also. The following code is a little prettier and get the same thing done more efficiently.

```
Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {

            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,

            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,

            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,

    };

String SELECTION = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";

Cursor contacts = managedQuery(contactUri, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null );
```

The above chunk of code returns a Cursor that points to the resulting query that only contains those rows that have a phone number. This is nice since you typically have many contacts without numbers. Furthermore, the PROJECTION limits the amount of data that is returned.

```
String key, value, phoneNumber; 

Hashtable contactPhoneInfo = new Hashtable<String, String>();

Uri phoneUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI; 

String [] PHONES_PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

String PHONE_SELECTION = null; 

        contacts.moveToFirst();

        do{

         long contactId = contacts.getLong(idColumnIndex); 

         PHONE_SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId; 

         Cursor phones = managedQuery(phoneUri,
           PHONES_PROJECTION,
           null, 
           null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " DESC");


         phones.moveToFirst(); 

         key = phones.getString(0).replaceAll("\\D", "");

         value = contacts.getString(nameColumnIndex); 

         contactPhoneInfo.put(key, value); 

        }while(contacts.moveToNext()); 

        contacts.close(); 
}
```

The above chunk gets the phone number associated with each contact id that has a phone number. I store all the info in a hash table and with a key value of the phone number. I stripped the phone number of all none digit info also. For some reason even though ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER is valid if you include that in the projection argument it breaks the query, I don't know why and it is frustrating that it does.

The second part of the code above is too slow, all the query calls just bog everything down. The following code is much faster. Just grab all the rows for the phone content and use the contact_ids to sort the data you want.

```
Cursor phones = managedQuery(phoneUri,
                PHONES_PROJECTION,
                PHONE_SELECTION, 
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY + " DESC");

contacts.moveToFirst();

        do{

            value = ""; 

            key = contacts.getString(idColumnIndex); 

            contactPhoneInfo.put(key, value);

        }while(contacts.moveToNext());

phones.moveToFirst();

        Set keySet = contactPhoneInfo.keySet(); 

        idColumnIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);

        int numColumnIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER); 

        do{

            key = phones.getString(idColumnIndex);  

            if(keySet.contains(key)){

                value = phones.getString(numColumnIndex).replaceAll("\\D", ""); 

                contactPhoneInfo.put(key, value); 

            }


        }while(phones.moveToNext());
```

You end up with a hashtable with all the info you want in it. Of course you could put whatever info you want into the data structure. The second way of doing it is much much faster.

Comment: If you just want some of the associated contact's info, you could also just use the implicit-join columns (like `ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME`) in your projection; then you wouldn't have to do a messy simulated join in Java.

Answer (score 18):

Just want to add, when you are retrieving the contacts you might get a lot of "garbage" contacts - for example some email addresses that a user has at some point send an email to, but are not aggregated... If you want only the contacts visible to the user, as in the Androids own contacts application you need to restrict the selection to only IN_VISIBLE_GROUP.

```
    String where = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "= ? ";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "1" };
```

Answer (score 14):

I think it is important to have the code from this URL http://coderzheaven.com/2011/06/get-all-details-from-contacts-in-android/ on StackOverflow cause at times links like that go down.

```
 public void readContacts(){
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                           new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                          String phone = pCur.getString(
                                 pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                          System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                    }
                    pCur.close();

                    // get email and type

                   Cursor emailCur = cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        String email = emailCur.getString(
                                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        String emailType = emailCur.getString(
                                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                      System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                    }
                    emailCur.close();

                    // Get note.......
                    String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                            Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                    if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                      System.out.println("Note " + note);
                    }
                    noteCur.close();

                    //Get Postal Address....

                    String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
//               Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
//                       null, null, null, null);
               Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                       null, addrWhere, addrWhereParams, null);

                    while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                        String street = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                        String city = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                        String state = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                        String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                        String country = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                        String type = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

                        // Do something with these....

                    }
                    addrCur.close();

                    // Get Instant Messenger.........
                    String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
                    if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String imName = imCur.getString(
                                 imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                        String imType;
                        imType = imCur.getString(
                                 imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                    }
                    imCur.close();

                    // Get Organizations.........

                    String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                    if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                        String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                    }
                    orgCur.close();
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

*emphasized text*

Comment: note that this code might have performance issues. see question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921109/get-contacts-performance-issue

Comment: Very inefficient, do not use this code... Could take a minute!

Answer (score 8):

I found very easy solution to read contacts. (boring to write code for reading each value so it's good to use wrapper class for contacts)

Of course `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>`

ContactList.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactList {
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

public ArrayList<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}

public void setContacts(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public void addContact(Contact contact) {
     this.contacts.add(contact);
 }

 public ContactList() {

 }
}
```

Contact.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Contact {
private String id;
 private String displayName;
 private ArrayList<Phone> phone;
 private ArrayList<Email> email;
 private ArrayList<String> notes;
 private ArrayList<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
 private ArrayList<IM> imAddresses;
 private Organization organization;
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getDisplayName() {
    return displayName;
}
public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
    this.displayName = displayName;
}
public ArrayList<Phone> getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(ArrayList<Phone> phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
public void addPhone(Phone phone) {
     this.phone.add(phone);
 }
public ArrayList<Email> getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(ArrayList<Email> email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void addEmail(Email email) {
     this.email.add(email);
 }
public ArrayList<String> getNotes() {
    return notes;
}
public void setNotes(ArrayList<String> notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}
public void AddNotes(String notes){
    this.notes.add(notes);
}
public ArrayList<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}
public void setAddresses(ArrayList<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}
public void addAddress(Address address) {
     this.addresses.add(address);
 }
public ArrayList<IM> getImAddresses() {
    return imAddresses;
}
public void setImAddresses(ArrayList<IM> imAddresses) {
    this.imAddresses = imAddresses;
}
public void addImAddresses(IM imAddr) {
     this.imAddresses.add(imAddr);
 }
public Organization getOrganization() {
    return organization;
}
public void setOrganization(Organization organization) {
    this.organization = organization;
}
}
```

Address.java

```
package com.test;

public class Address {
private String poBox;
 private String street;
 private String city;
 private String state;
 private String postalCode;
 private String country;
 private String type;
 private String asString = "";

 public String getType() {
     return type;
 }
 public void setType(String type) {
     this.type = type;
 }
 public String getPoBox() {
     return poBox;
 }
 public void setPoBox(String poBox) {
     this.poBox = poBox;
 }
 public String getStreet() {
     return street;
 }
 public void setStreet(String street) {
     this.street = street;
 }
 public String getCity() {
     return city;
 }
 public void setCity(String city) {
     this.city = city;
 }
 public String getState() {
     return state;
 }
 public void setState(String state) {
     this.state = state;
 }
 public String getPostalCode() {
     return postalCode;
 }
 public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
     this.postalCode = postalCode;
 }
 public String getCountry() {
     return country;
 }
 public void setCountry(String country) {
     this.country = country;
 }
 public String toString() {
     if (this.asString.length() > 0) {
         return(this.asString);
     } else {
         String addr = "";
         if (this.getPoBox() != null) {
             addr = addr + this.getPoBox() + "n";
         }
         if (this.getStreet() != null) {
             addr = addr + this.getStreet() + "n";
         }
         if (this.getCity() != null) {
             addr = addr + this.getCity() + ", ";
         }
         if (this.getState() != null) {
             addr = addr + this.getState() + " ";
         }
         if (this.getPostalCode() != null) {
             addr = addr + this.getPostalCode() + " ";
         }
         if (this.getCountry() != null) {
             addr = addr + this.getCountry();
         }
         return(addr);
     }
 }

 public Address(String asString, String type) {
     this.asString = asString;
     this.type = type;
 }

 public Address(String poBox, String street, String city, String state, 
         String postal, String country, String type) {
     this.setPoBox(poBox);
      this.setStreet(street);
     this.setCity(city);
     this.setState(state);
     this.setPostalCode(postal);
     this.setCountry(country);
     this.setType(type);
 }
}
```

Email.java

```
package com.test;

public class Email {
private String address;
 private String type;
 public String getAddress() {
     return address;
 }
 public void setAddress(String address) {
     this.address = address;
 }
 public String getType() {
     return type;
 }
 public void setType(String t) {
     this.type = t;
 }

 public Email(String a, String t) {
     this.address = a;
     this.type = t;
 }
}
```

Im.java

```
package com.test;

public class IM {
private String name;
 private String type;
 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }
 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }
 public String getType() {
     return type;
 }
 public void setType(String type) {
     this.type = type;
 }

 public IM(String name, String type) {
     this.name = name;
     this.type = type;
 }
}
```

Organization.java

```
package com.test;

public class Organization {
private String organization = "";
 private String title = "";
 public String getOrganization() {
     return organization;
 }
 public void setOrganization(String organization) {
     this.organization = organization;
 }
 public String getTitle() {
     return title;
 }
 public void setTitle(String title) {
     this.title = title;
 }

 public Organization() {

 }
 public Organization(String org, String title) {
     this.organization = org;
     this.title = title;
 }
}
```

Phone.java

```
package com.test;

public class Phone {
private String number;
 private String type;

 public String getNumber() {
     return number;
 }

 public void setNumber(String number) {
     this.number = number;
 }

 public String getType() {
     return type;
 }

 public void setType(String type) {
     this.type = type;
 }

 public Phone(String n, String t) {
     this.number = n;
     this.type = t;
 }
}
```

ContactAPI.java

```
package com.test;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;

public abstract class ContactAPI {
private static ContactAPI api;

 public static ContactAPI getAPI() {
     if (api == null) {
         String apiClass;
         if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
             apiClass = "com.*********.ContactAPISdk5";
         } else {
             apiClass = "com.*********.ContactAPISdk3";
         }

         try {
             Class<? extends ContactAPI> realClass = Class.forName(apiClass).
                 asSubclass(ContactAPI.class);
             api = realClass.newInstance();
         } catch (Exception e) {
             throw new IllegalStateException(e);
         }

     }
     return api;
 }

 public abstract Intent getContactIntent();

 public abstract ContactList newContactList();

 public abstract Cursor getCur();
 public abstract void setCur(Cursor cur);

 public abstract ContentResolver getCr();
 public abstract void setCr(ContentResolver cr);

}
```

ContactAPISdk5.java

```
package com.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class ContactAPISdk5 extends ContactAPI {

 private Cursor cur;
 private ContentResolver cr;


 public Cursor getCur() {
     return cur;
 }

 public void setCur(Cursor cur) {
     this.cur = cur;
 }

 public ContentResolver getCr() {
     return cr;
 }

 public void setCr(ContentResolver cr) {
     this.cr = cr;
 }

 public Intent getContactIntent() {
     return(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI));
 }

 public ContactList newContactList() {
     ContactList contacts = new ContactList();
     String id;

     this.cur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
             null, null, null, null);
     if (this.cur.getCount() > 0) {
         while (cur.moveToNext()) {
             Contact c = new Contact();
             id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
             c.setId(id);
             c.setDisplayName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
             if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                 c.setPhone(this.getPhoneNumbers(id));
             }
             c.setEmail(this.getEmailAddresses(id));
             c.setNotes(this.getContactNotes(id));
             c.setAddresses(this.getContactAddresses(id));
             c.setImAddresses(this.getIM(id));
             c.setOrganization(this.getContactOrg(id));
             contacts.addContact(c);
         }
     }
     return(contacts);
 }

 public ArrayList<Phone> getPhoneNumbers(String id) {
     ArrayList<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();

     Cursor pCur = this.cr.query(
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
             null, 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
             new String[]{id}, null);
     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
         phones.add(new Phone(
                 pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                 , pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE))
         ));

     } 
     pCur.close();
     return(phones);
 }

 public ArrayList<Email> getEmailAddresses(String id) {
     ArrayList<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();

     Cursor emailCur = this.cr.query( 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
             null,
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
             new String[]{id}, null); 
     while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
         // This would allow you get several email addresses
         Email e = new Email(emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA))
                 ,emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE))  
                 );
         emails.add(e);
     } 
     emailCur.close();
     return(emails);
 }

 public ArrayList<String> getContactNotes(String id) {
     ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
     String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id, 
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 
     Cursor noteCur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null); 
     if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) { 
         String note = noteCur.getString(noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
         if (note.length() > 0) {
             notes.add(note);
         }
     } 
     noteCur.close();
     return(notes);
 }

 public ArrayList<Address> getContactAddresses(String id) {
     ArrayList<Address> addrList = new ArrayList<Address>();

     String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id, 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 

     Cursor addrCur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null); 
     while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
         String poBox = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
         String street = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
         String city = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
         String state = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
         String postalCode = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
         String country = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
         String type = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));
         Address a = new Address(poBox, street, city, state, postalCode, country, type);
         addrList.add(a);
     } 
     addrCur.close();
     return(addrList);
 }

 public ArrayList<IM> getIM(String id) {
     ArrayList<IM> imList = new ArrayList<IM>();
     String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id, 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 

     Cursor imCur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null); 
     if (imCur.moveToFirst()) { 
         String imName = imCur.getString(imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
         String imType;
         imType = imCur.getString(imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
         if (imName.length() > 0) {
             IM im = new IM(imName, imType);
             imList.add(im);
         }
     } 
     imCur.close();
     return(imList);
 }

 public Organization getContactOrg(String id) {
     Organization org = new Organization();
     String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id, 
             ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}; 

     Cursor orgCur = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null);

     if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) { 
         String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
         String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
         if (orgName.length() > 0) {
             org.setOrganization(orgName);
             org.setTitle(title);
         }
     } 
     orgCur.close();
     return(org);
 }

 }
```

ContactAPISdk3.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.Contacts;
import android.provider.Contacts.People;

public class ContactAPISdk3 extends ContactAPI {

 private Cursor cur;
 private ContentResolver cr;

 public Cursor getCur() {
     return cur;
 }

 public void setCur(Cursor cur) {
     this.cur = cur;
 }

 public ContentResolver getCr() {
     return cr;
 }

 public void setCr(ContentResolver cr) {
     this.cr = cr;
 }

 public Intent getContactIntent() {
     return(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI));
 }

 public ContactList newContactList() {
     ContactList contacts = new ContactList();
     String id="";

     this.cur = this.cr.query(People.CONTENT_URI, 
             null, null, null, null);
     if (this.cur.getCount() > 0) {
         while (cur.moveToNext()) {
             Contact c = new Contact();
             id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People._ID));
             c.setId(id);
             c.setDisplayName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.DISPLAY_NAME)));
             if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.PRIMARY_PHONE_ID))) > 0) {
                 c.setPhone(this.getPhoneNumbers(id));
             }
             c.setEmail(this.getEmailAddresses(id));
             ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
             notes.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NOTES)));
             c.setNotes(notes);
             c.setAddresses(this.getContactAddresses(id));
             c.setImAddresses(this.getIM(id));
             c.setOrganization(this.getContactOrg(id));
             contacts.addContact(c);
         }
     }
     return(contacts);
 }

 public ArrayList<Phone> getPhoneNumbers(String id) {
     ArrayList<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();

     Cursor pCur = this.cr.query(
             Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, 
             null, 
             Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID +" = ?", 
             new String[]{id}, null);
     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
         phones.add(new Phone(
                 pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER))
                 , pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.TYPE))
         ));

     } 
     pCur.close();
     return(phones);
 }

 public ArrayList<Email> getEmailAddresses(String id) {
     ArrayList<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();

     Cursor emailCur = this.cr.query( 
             Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI, 
             null,
             Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID + " = ?", 
             new String[]{id}, null); 
     while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
         // This would allow you get several email addresses
         Email e = new Email(emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethods.DATA))
                 ,emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_TYPE))  
                 );
         emails.add(e);
     } 
     emailCur.close();
     return(emails);
 }

 public ArrayList<Address> getContactAddresses(String id) {
     ArrayList<Address> addrList = new ArrayList<Address>();

     String where = Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID + " = ? AND " + Contacts.ContactMethods.KIND + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id, 
             Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_POSTAL_ITEM_TYPE}; 

     Cursor addrCur = this.cr.query(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null); 
     while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
         String addr = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethodsColumns.DATA));
         String type = addrCur.getString(addrCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethodsColumns.TYPE));
         Address a = new Address(addr, type);
         addrList.add(a);
     } 
     addrCur.close();
     return(addrList);
 }

 public ArrayList<IM> getIM(String id) {
     ArrayList<IM> imList = new ArrayList<IM>();
     String where = Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID + " = ? AND " + Contacts.ContactMethods.KIND + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id, 
             Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_IM_ITEM_TYPE}; 

     Cursor imCur = this.cr.query(Contacts.ContactMethods.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null); 
     if (imCur.moveToFirst()) { 
         String imName = imCur.getString(imCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethodsColumns.DATA));
         String imType = imCur.getString(imCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.ContactMethodsColumns.TYPE));
         if (imName.length() > 0) {
             IM im = new IM(imName, imType);
             imList.add(im);
         }
     } 
     imCur.close();
     return(imList);
 }

 public Organization getContactOrg(String id) {
     Organization org = new Organization();
     String where = Contacts.ContactMethods.PERSON_ID + " = ?"; 
     String[] whereParameters = new String[]{id}; 

     Cursor orgCur = this.cr.query(Contacts.Organizations.CONTENT_URI, null, where, whereParameters, null);

     if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) { 
         String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Organizations.COMPANY));
         String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Organizations.TITLE));
         if (orgName.length() > 0) {
             org.setOrganization(orgName);
             org.setTitle(title);
         }
     } 
     orgCur.close();
     return(org);
 }
 }
```

**Note** : Don't forget to change package name instead `*******`.

[Source](http://www.cnblogs.com/lycoris/archive/2011/05/13/2037716.html) (link can be die any time :))

Answer (score 6):

Put this ....

```
Cursor phones = 

    getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext())
                {
                String Name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String Number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
}
```

Let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 3):

This part wouldn't work for me:

```
 while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
     String phoneNumber = phones.getString( 
       phones.getColumnIndex( 
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));                 
    }
```

If I use this, though, it does:

```
 while (phones.moveToNext()) { 
                                  String pdata = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA));
                                  Log.v("DATA",pdata);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use "ContactManager" example from android developer's site 
            (OR)
Go to the location where you have set the path to download android-sdk in your system. In android-sdk-mac_x86/samples/android-10 folder, you can see  "ContactManager" example.

I have tried using this example, worked well in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Samsung Galaxy Note 4, and I donno why none of the above worked for me.
I mixed up some and made this woking..

```
    Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    people.moveToFirst();
    while(people.moveToNext()) {
       int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
       String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
       int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);
       String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
       dbWriter.execSQL("Insert Into ContactsList (ContactName, ContactNumber) Values (" +
                 "'" + contact.replace("'",  "''") + "', '" + number.replace("'",  "''") + "')");
    }
    people.close();
```