# What is the intent associated with "View work address" in Contacts / Contact Card?

Tags: android

I'd like to register an intent filter so that the "View work address" action in the People app can launch my app - but what is that intent ?

Comment: @down voter: whats the problem ? Voting down without reason accomplishes NOTHING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching all day through the Contacts source code, I came up with the following solution:

1. go to the Google market and install "Intent Intercept"
2. capture the data. In this case it looks like this:

> **Action:** android.intent.action.VIEW
>
> **Data:** content://com.android.contacts/data/1425
>
> **Uri:** content://com.android.contacts/data/1425
>
> **Type**: null
>
> **3 activities match this intent:**
>
> com.telenav.app.android.sprint
>
> com.google.android.apps.maps
>
> uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept

I then went to the documentation to find out what I should have gotten...

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

As you can imagine, I was shocked not to see a "geo" scheme used. (which explains why I couldn't find the geo URI in the source code).

---

**EDIT:** I am trying to implement the app's intent-filter; it's not so easy to hack this...

this works - but it also captures intents other than "View work address" (which is not good)

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" android:scheme="content" android:host="com.android.contacts" />

        </intent-filter>
```

---

EDIT 2: this is the best intent-filter I can come up with for this scenario

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/*" android:host="com.android.contacts" />
        </intent-filter>
```

---

EDIT 3: I can do better ... this is the EXACT intent filter to use

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/*" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:pathPrefix="/data" android:scheme="content"/>
        </intent-filter>
```