# How do I get contacts and text message info

Tags: android

How would I use the SQL DB info and such to get info about contacts and text messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't read contacts from the database directly. Use appropriate ContentProviders to access it. I guess there is no other choice beside reading from database for SMS. You can refer to existing threads on reading [contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0) and [text message info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848728/how-can-i-read-sms-messages-from-the-inbox-programmatically-in-android) on StackOverflow itself.