# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2

Tags: android, contacts, android-cursor

Below is my codes and I got the `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2 error. Can anyone tell me how to solve it?

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null, null, null);
  if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
    cur.getColumnIndex(People.PRIMARY_PHONE_ID))) > 0) {

   Cursor pCur = cr.query(
     Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI, 
     null, 
     Contacts.Phones.PERSON_ID +" = ?", 
     new String[]{id}, null);
   int i=0;
   int pCount = pCur.getCount();
   String[] phoneNum = new String[pCount];
   String[] phoneType = new String[pCount];
   while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
    phoneNum[i] = pCur.getString(
      pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.NUMBER));
    phoneType[i] = pCur.getString(
      pCur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.TYPE));
    i++;
   } 
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What is `phoneType`. Also, you need to edit your question and format your code correctly.

Comment: may be this error is coming bcoz you have not added any contacts in ur emulator..........

Comment: did you add the appropriate permissions to AndroidManifest?

Comment: Falmarri: I want to get the mobile phone number.
Chirag: I have added 2 contacts in my emulator.
Sriran: I have added the permission. 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>

Answer (score 63):

If you are accessing data from `Cursor` object than you must have to position the `Cursor` object.

Actually you have to position `Cursor` to the first row before you try to access data from it.

Put the line `cur.moveToFirst();` after the line `Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
    null, null, null, null);` in your code.

And also ensure that you are not using and older API for retrieving Contacts.

Comment: tks. i got another error nw. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed

Comment: It means probably you are using an Invalid column name. And if you only want to read contacts (mobile numbers) then have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0

Comment: ok. tks. i will try out the link. if i gt any further qns i will post it hre again.

Comment: Yes, thanks, Vikas.  I seem to forget to call moveToFirst() every few months (just long enough to forget how important it is!).