# Getting android contacts

Tags: android, contacts

Im trying to get a list of all the contacts and there email address.

Currently im using this code, however I get a lot of duplicate names and emails. What i want is just one person and one email. Is there a way I can merge contacts while querying for them?

Also im just looking for a > 2.0 solution.

```
    private void init() {

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id},null); 
        while (emailCur.moveToNext()) { 
                String email = emailCur.getString( emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                Log.e("Email",name+" "+email);
            } 
            emailCur.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: try this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/

Comment: Well what im really trying at the end is to build a multiple contact selector. So the user can come on and select multiple people to email. But ill take a look at that link and see if theres code i can learn from.Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this : **[How to read contacts on Android 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)**

Comment: @Faisal I've seen a lot of multiple contact picker out there on the internets. On this website too. As for your question. As per your db query you are printing multiple emails with the same name. Check your code again.

Comment: I dint get the exact question. What did you meant by "I get a lot of duplicate names and emails". With the above code you must be getting the Display name of a contact and its corresponding mail ID's. What modification are you looking for ?

Comment: Oh man I had one of those moments, The code above i copied from a source on the internet and I was only looking at the second loop. not the first one. In any case thanks guys for helping me realize that!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try out the working code below.

```
public class dddddddddd extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);
        readContacts();
    }

    public void readContacts(){
         ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

         if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                    // get the phone number
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                           ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                           new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                          String phone = pCur.getString(
                                 pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                          System.out.println("phone" + phone);
                    }
                    pCur.close();


                    // get email and type


                   Cursor emailCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                        // This would allow you get several email addresses
                            // if the email addresses were stored in an array
                        String email = emailCur.getString(
                                      emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                        String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

                        int type = emailCur.getInt(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                        String customLabel = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.LABEL));
                        CharSequence CustomemailType = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(this.getResources(), type, customLabel);

                      //System.out.println("Email " + email + " Email Type : " + emailType);
                    }
                    emailCur.close();

                    // Get note.......
                    String noteWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] noteWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

                     Cursor noteCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, 
                             noteWhere, noteWhereParams, null);
                    if (noteCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String note = noteCur.getString(
                        noteCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Note.NOTE));
                      System.out.println("Note " + note);
                    }
                    noteCur.close();

                    //Get Postal Address....

                    String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID 
                            + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor addrCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, null, null, null);
                    while(addrCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String poBox = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POBOX));
                        String street = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
                        String city = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
                        String state = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));
                        String postalCode = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
                        String country = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
                        String type = addrCur.getString(
                                     addrCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE));

                        // Do something with these....

                    }
                    addrCur.close();

                    // Get Instant Messenger.........
                    String imWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " 
                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] imWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor imCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, imWhere, imWhereParams, null);
                    if (imCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String imName = imCur.getString(
                                 imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.DATA));
                        String imType;
                        imType = imCur.getString(
                                 imCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.TYPE));
                    }
                    imCur.close();

                    // Get Organizations.........

                    String orgWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?";
                    String[] orgWhereParams = new String[]{id,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
                    Cursor orgCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                                null, orgWhere, orgWhereParams, null);
                    if (orgCur.moveToFirst()) {
                        String orgName = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA));
                        String title = orgCur.getString(orgCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.TITLE));
                    }
                    orgCur.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```