# implementing contacts in android in list and saving contact in database

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)

I am developing an android application in which i have to implement contacts in a list and save all the contacts in the database.I have looked around a sample of codes.i have used content provider and cursor adapter for fetching contacts.But it did not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a similar thing for my asignment at school. Here is what i ended up with:

```
private List<String> emailAdresses;

private List<String> readEmailAdresses() {
        if(emailAdresses == null)
            emailAdresses = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            String emailAdress = null;
            Cursor emailCursor = managedQuery(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Email.CONTACT_ID, Email.DATA1 }, null, null,
                    Email.CONTACT_ID);

            while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                emailAdress = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(Email.DATA1));
                emailAdresses.add(emailAdress);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Retreive failed", ex);
        }

        return emailAdresses;
    }
```

Just make sure you use this permission for the example:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: @xstudio u made 2 classes which u have written code???

Comment: I updated my answer, this provides sample code, the rest is up to you. Google is your friend.