# ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY will give the Display name

Tags: android, contacts

After spending a few weeks on an App for my company all my questions were answered here. But now i have something very strange which i have nothing found for so I hope somebody can help me.

I try to read Android Contacts. Actually everything is working fine except the company name. I am not able to read it. On the other hand writing the company name is no problem.

When I try to read / get the company name it will display the full name of the contact on my mobile device and the phone number on the emulator.

Here is the code where i read the company name:

```
Cursor comCur = managedQuery ( 
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, 
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                    new String[]{id}, null); 
comCur.moveToFirst();
String company = comCur.getString(comCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY));
```

When I debug the app, the variable company has the full name or the phone number but never the company name.

I have the same code for other fields like mail-address, the only difference is that it has

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
```

instead of

```
ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI
```

But if i understand it the right way my code is not wrong...or is it?

I am sure you guys can help me...PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can refer to the following link for the answer. [How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0). i checked it out and it's working