# get contacts performance issue

Tags: java, android, android-cursor

I am trying to get contacts of the android device.
I found a great sample code [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/06/13/get-all-details-from-contacts-in-android/)

However, when trying to populate a `ListActivity` with `ArrayAdapter` that is using that code it is taking a lot of time - almost 4 seconds on galaxy s2 and much more on older devices.
I need to improve that performance. What I thought is to implements `Cursor` that will hold more than one dimension `Cursor`, and use `SimpleCursorAdapter` as the list adapter.
I see few problems with this approach:

- I don't know how to get item at specific position.
- each cursor has different columns.

Is there a better/easier way to do that?

EDIT:

here is my code:

```
public List<ContactData> readContacts(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    List<ContactData> cd = new ArrayList<ContactData>();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
           null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
       while (cur.moveToNext()) {
           String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
           if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

               // get the phone number
               Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                      new String[]{id}, null);
               while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phone = pCur.getString(
                            pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     if (!Utils.isEmpty(phone)) {
                         cd.add(new ContactData(id, name, phone));
                     }
               }
               pCur.close();


           }
       }
  }
    return cd;
}
```

EDIT 2:

managed to fix it by changing it to only one query:

```
public List<ContactData> readContacts(){
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    List<ContactData> cd = new ArrayList<ContactData>();
               Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                       new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY},
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IS NOT NULL",
                                      null, 
                                      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY);
               while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                     String id = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
                     String name = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
                         ContactData cd1 = contactDataProvider.get();
                         cd1.id = id;
                         cd1.name = name;
                         cd1.phone = phone;
                         cd.add(cd1);
               }
               pCur.close();
    return cd;
}
```

Comment: What is the complete and precise list of pieces of data from a contact that you wish to render in each of your `ListFragment` rows?

Comment: I added code sample, hope it explains (id,name,phone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get name and ID at the same time you get the phone number:

```
String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                      new String[]{id}, null);
```

This eliminates the per-row sub-query.

Comment: it works, thanks! I used it but also removed the filtering by id to get all phones of all users.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `Cursor` is a great approach for this problem. To get retrieve information from a specific position, you can use `Cursor.moveToPosition(int position)`. Then you can access any field of the `Cursor`, in this case a `String`,  using `Cursor.getString(int columnIndex)`.

Take a look at the [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) documentation for more details.

The best part about this approach is that you can implement a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to do the background data retrieval for you. It also automatically handles repopulating your `ListView` on data changes, orientation changes, etc. Check out [this great tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/) for more explanation.

Comment: CursorLoader is def a great way to do. Also be careful nesting queries inside of each other. Lastly, you want to make sure that you only select the information that you need.