# Importing Contacts to an android app

Tags: android, text, message, contacts

I am trying to make a text messaging app for android.
I would like the layout to be pretty similar to that of the 
native app, but it will include additional features. I need to create 
a contacts screen that is automatically synchronized with the Android contacts. 
Any ideas on where to start with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to look at reading contacts from the android device, that can be found here -

- [How to read contacts on Android 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721279/how-to-read-contacts-on-android-2-0)

I would display them in a list view, which you can look at here -

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html
- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: If this answer helped you, click the little check mark in the top corner underneath the post score to accept this answer and mark it as solved.