# How to get some informations of a contact by using cursor loader?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I want to get: id, name, phone number and company of all contacts which stored in default contact of the phone. After that, I want to display them into  list view.
I use cursor loader to do that. BUT, i have just get id and name of each contact. I CAN NOT get phone number & company. You can see all my code below.

I think I may be wrong at: PROJECTION & SELECTION (?) 
What about your opinion?? Could you show me what my error is?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
final Context context = this;
protected Intent intent;
protected TextView contactId;
protected ListView lv;
protected EditText inputSearch;
protected SimpleAdapter adapter;
SimpleCursorAdapter curAdapter;
public MatrixCursor extras;

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA};

    static final String SELECTION = "("+ 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " AND " + 
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " AND " + 
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + 
            ")";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] fromColumns = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.DATA};

    int[] toViews = {       R.id.contactId,
                            R.id.contactName,
                            R.id.phone,
                            R.id.company};

    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.view_contact_entry, null,
            fromColumns, toViews, 0);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, "DISPLAY_NAME ASC");           
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

OK. And here is all information in logcat:
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-rXZ0iSq_CEg/Uf9bk-CmwBI/AAAAAAAAAVQ/SvieJesBqqQ/s800/Untitled.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing each `ContactsContract.Contacts._ID` for `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID`

and `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` for `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME`

Comment: Great idea, Renan Bandeira!
I try to do it and get id, name, phone number successfully. BUT, what about company name (?)

Comment: Sorry, forgot this one. Here it is: 
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY

Comment: I have get value of ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.COMPANY of each contact. They are PHONE NUMBER (?)
Values of Organization.COMPANY & Phone.DISPLAY_NAME are the same (!)
what's wrong?

Comment: My bad. I had never tried to get Organization info and just thought it would be ok. Look at this code, it will help you. Or just copy and paste the method that works here.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9723988/2652124